# Drupal: Save a file from filesystem

Tags: php, drupal

I want to save a file, that I have created in the temp directory, into drupal. But file_save requests a file object but I have just the real path.

```
$imageId =file_save('/tmp/proj/media/cover.jpg']);
```

Comment: ('/tmp/proj/media/cover.jpg'`]`); why is that there. If you do a simple google search, you'll know this arguement is an object of  `stdClass` http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [file_save_data function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_data/7), or possibly [file_unmanaged_save_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_save_data/7), instead of file_save().

Answer (score 0):

file_save(stdClass $file) save a file object. You are trying to download a file.

You can do as

```
$file = '/tmp/proj/media/cover.jpg';
// Get the file size
$details = stat($file);
$filesize = $details['size'];

// Get the path to your Drupal site's files directory 
$dest = file_directory_path();

// Copy the file to the Drupal files directory 
if(!file_copy($file, $dest)) {
    echo "Failed to move file: $file.\n";
    return;
} else {
    // file_move might change the name of the file
    $name = basename($file);
}

// Build the file object
$file_obj = new stdClass();
$file_obj->filename = $name;
$file_obj->filepath = $file;
$file_obj->filemime =  file_get_mimetype($name);
$file_obj->filesize = $filesize;
$file_obj->filesource = $name;
// You can change this to the UID you want
$file_obj->uid = 1;
$file_obj->status = FILE_STATUS_TEMPORARY;
$file_obj->timestamp = time();
$file_obj->list = 1;
$file_obj->new = true;

// Save file to files table
drupal_write_record('files', $file_obj);
```

I hope this will help you.